# Can sub-Gaussian distributions have non-zero mean?

Tags: normal-distribution, mean, multiarmed-bandit

A random variable $X$ is sub-Gaussian if there exists a $b>0$ such that for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $$\mathbb{E}(\exp(tX)) \leq \exp(b^2t^2/2).$$ 
According to some sources online such as [here](https://sites.ualberta.ca/~omarr/publications/subgaussians.pdf) we have that $\mathbb{E}(X)=0$ (see proposition 2.1). Another [source](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-s997-high-dimensional-statistics-spring-2015/lecture-notes/MIT18_S997S15_Chapter1.pdf) (see definition 1.2) defines random variables as sub Gaussian if it satisfies the above equation and that $\mathbb{E}(X)=0$.

I've been reading into a variant of the multi armed bandit problem recently called rotting bandits. The latest version of the preprint is [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.07274.pdf), where the authors state:

> When arm $i$ is pulled for the $n^{th}$ time, the agent receives a time-independent, $σ^2$ sub-Gaussian random reward, $r_t$, with mean $\mu_i(n).$

Another paper on the more general problem of [Multi-Armed Bandits with Non-Stationary Rewards](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.10657.pdf) references the previously linked paper saying the authors analyze

> the setting where the rewards are $\sigma^2$ sub-Gaussian rewards with mean $\mu_i^c+t^{-\theta_i^*}$ at time $t$ for $\theta_i^* \in \Theta=\{\theta_1\,\theta_2,\ldots\}.$

My confusion here is that the reward in the rotting bandit scenario are sub-Gaussian with potentially non-zero means, contradiction my linked reading into sub-Gaussian distributions. Can anyone identify where I have made a mistake here?

Note: I'm aware Arxiv is not a peer-reviewed platform however the authors come from reputable institutions.

Comment: I suppose it's just a matter of translating the variable by adding or subtracting a constant $\mu$. The definitions you give initially only want to treat standardized variables for convenience. But I don't see the problem to consider variables that would have a non-zero mean.

Comment: @Raskolnikov After reading the papers some more I think you're right. Am I correct in thinking that formally if a random variable is sub-Gaussian it has zero mean and that the bandit papers are actually suggesting the reward is the sum of some random variable (which defines the mean) plus a sub-Gaussian? I just feel like the bandit papers are abusing the definition a bit by calling the shifted sub-Gaussian a sub-Gaussian. I come from more of a math/computer-science background so I'm not sure if this is common in statistics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is standard in the bandit literature to abuse notation by considering a random variable $X$ to be $\sigma$-subgaussian if the noise $X - \mathbb{E}[X]$ is $\sigma$-subgaussian.

See the note on page 78 of [Tor Lattimore and Csaba Szepesvari's book](https://tor-lattimore.com/downloads/book/book.pdf)

Answer (score 9):

The first comment on this question is incorrect strictly speaking; [the proposition you link to](https://sites.ualberta.ca/~omarr/publications/subgaussians.pdf) shows that having zero mean ***is a necessary condition for being sub-Gaussian***.

In some sense, you can still get a useful notion for non-centered random variables to be sub-Gaussian, *but only if you change the definition*.

If you look at [one of the other sources you linked to](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-s997-high-dimensional-statistics-spring-2015/lecture-notes/MIT18_S997S15_Chapter1.pdf), if you look at the "converse proposition", which shows that the tail bounds imply the MGF bound up to a multiplicative constant in the exponent, you will see that the assumption that $\mathbb{E}Y=0$ is used implicitly. (It appears to be a typo that Lemma 1.5 omits the assumption in its statement, but it is clearly used in the proof, and when my professor assigned it as a homework assignment, he specifically made sure to add the assumption to the problem.) In order for this Taylor expansion of the MGF to be correct: $$\mathbb{E}e^{\lambda Y} = 1 + \sum\limits_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{\lambda^k \mathbb{E}Y^k}{k!} \,, $$ for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, we need that $\mathbb{E}Y=0$. Admittedly the assumption does not appear to be used in an essential way in that lemma, since we can still bound $\mathbb{E}Y$ by $\mathbb{E}|Y| \le \sigma \sqrt{2\pi}$, and this doesn't appear large enough to prevent the upper bounds user later in the proof from working.

To show more convincingly that the definition of sub-Gaussian as stated just doesn't work when $\mathbb{E}Y\not=0$, let's try to show that if $\mathbb{E}Y \not=0$ and $Y \in SG(\sigma^2)$, then $(Y - \mathbb{E}Y) \in SG(\sigma^2)$, which we would need to be true for it to be the case that , for any mean-zero sub-Gaussian $X$, $X+b$ is also sub-Gaussian for any constant $b \not=0$. The proof founders on an irresolvable problem.

Now we definitionally have that $(Y - \mathbb{E}Y) \in SG(\sigma^2) \iff \forall \lambda \in \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{E}e^{\lambda(Y-\mathbb{E})} \le \exp(\frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 \lambda^2)$.

Before going any further, let's just note that we *shouldn't* expect this to work out well. $\exp(\frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 \lambda^2)$ is the MGF bound for a Gaussian *centered at 0*. So even if we had a "sub-Gaussian" random variable $Y$ which wasn't centered at $0$, we still wouldn't expect it to satisfy *this* MGF bound (thus it *couldn't* satisfy the conventional definition of sub-Gaussian), we would expect it to an MGF bound corresponding to $\mathscr{N}(\mathbb{E}Y, \sigma^2)$, which is different than the one above, for $\mathscr{N}(0,\sigma^2)$.

Anyway, $$\mathbb{E}e^{\lambda(Y - \mathbb{E}Y)} = e^{-\lambda \mathbb{E}Y} \mathbb{E}e^{\lambda Y} \le e^{-\lambda \mathbb{E}Y} e^{\frac{1}{2}\lambda^2 \sigma^2} = \exp\left( \frac{1}{2}\lambda^2\left(\sigma^2 - \frac{2 \mathbb{E}Y}{\lambda}\right) \right)\,.$$ So if we want to show that this is sub-Gaussian, there needs to exists a constant $\tau >0$, such that ***for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$***, one has $$ \tau^2 \ge \sigma^2 - \frac{2 \mathbb{E}Y}{\lambda} \,,$$ which is clearly impossible, since as one "ranges over" all possible values of $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, $-\frac{1}{\lambda}$ is a function of $\lambda$ which is unbounded from above.

Note also that the tail bound definitions are in terms of $t \ge 0$, i.e. they implicitly assume/require that the random variable is centered around $0$, i.e. has zero expectation. Thus heuristically we should also expect the tail bound definitions to fail when $\mathbb{E}Y \not=0$, or at least become very messy.

One consequence of the tail bound definition is that $\mathbb{P}(|Y| > t) \le \exp\left( \frac{-t^2}{2\sigma^2} \right)$ for all $t \ge 0$. If $Y - \mathbb{E}Y$ is also to be sub-Gaussian, then we would need that $$\mathbb{P}(|Y - \mathbb{E}Y| > t) \le \exp\left( \frac{-t^2}{2\sigma^2} \right) \quad \text{for all }t \ge 0 \,. $$

Now the event $\{ | Y - \mathbb{E}Y| > t\}$ is equal to the event $$ \{ Y > t + \mathbb{E}Y \} \cup \{  Y < -(t - \mathbb{E}Y) \} \,. $$ Even if it is possible for the required bound on the probability of these events, *for all $t \ge 0$*, to hold if $Y$ were sub-Gaussian but $\mathbb{E}Y \not=0$ (I'm not sure how to prove or disprove that it is or isn't though - intuitively, since the events aren't centered at $0$, but range over all possible values of $t \ge 0$, conceivably we might get two contradictory bounds from two different values of $t$), the fact that it holds would not follow from the assumption that $Y$ was sub-Gaussian. This also means (or at least suggests) that in general we cannot conclude that translates of sub-Gaussian random variables will still be sub-Gaussian.

This is all perhaps somewhat disingenuous though, since even to the extent that any of it is true, I have yet to acknowledge how these arguments all suggest the same way to generalize the definition of sub-Gaussian. Namely, I claim that the following three definitions are equivalent:

- $Y$ is sub-Gaussian [*sensu lato*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sensu_lato) if and only if $(Y - \mathbb{E}Y)$ is sub-Gaussian [*sensu stricto*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sensu_stricto).
- $Y$ is sub-Gaussian sensu lato if and only if its moment generating function is bounded by the moment generating function of $\mathscr{N}(\mathbb{E}Y, \sigma^2)$ for some $\sigma > 0$.
- $Y$ is sub-Gaussian sensu lato if and only if for some $\sigma >0$, for all $t \ge 0$, $$\mathbb{P}(Y > \mathbb{E}Y + t) \le \exp\left( \frac{-t^2}{2\sigma^2} \right) \quad \text{and} \quad \mathbb{P}(Y < \mathbb{E}Y - t) \le \exp\left( \frac{-t^2}{2\sigma^2} \right) \,. $$